# New integration symbol

Tags: custom-notation

Is there a way to introduce a new integration symbol? Specifically I want to be able to use ⨍.
I have no problem entering it into mm, but the size does not change like the standard \int does.

Comment: For the benefit of those (like me) whose browser doesn't render that symbol: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2a0d/index.htm

Comment: The unicode character `2a0d` is not recognized by _Mathematica_ as having any special significance and, therefore, there is no built-in support for formatting it as there is for `\[Integral]`.

Comment: If you need this purely for typesetting, it may be possible to use `Overlay` to put a `\[Dash]` on top of an integral sign ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by m_goldberg:

> The unicode character 2a0d is not recognized by Mathematica as having any special significance and, therefore, there is no built-in
>   support for formatting it as there is for ∫ (`\[Integral]`)

Moreover, if you enter it as a Unicode character using `\:2a0d` Mathematica displays it as an empty box. It doesn't look like there's any support for doing what you want.